# What is the behavior of multiple unseparated equality comparisons in C?

Tags: c, syntax

I made a typo while I was writing some `C` code and noticed that `CLion` did not see anything wrong with doing

```
while(line != NULL != 0)
```

In fact, it actually compiles and runs without error (though it does always return true)

I did some further testing, and found that it actually does return false sometimes

```
//true
if(1 != 0 == 1)
//false
if(1 != 0 == 0)
//true
if(1 != 0 > 2)
```

At first I thought it was essentially doing

```
if((1!=0) == true)
```

but that last check has me completely lost.

Comment: precedence..... > binds tighter than !=  . that's why you use parentheses if ever in any doubt

Comment: So whats the equality comparison equivalent of PEMDAS? Apparently > is evaluated before !=

Comment: that's what I just said!

Comment: You edited it into your comment while I was writing my reply

Comment: I am fairly open to elementary questions, but I have to say that this is pretty fundamental. It is something that is covered in any C textbook, and the proper way to learn a language is by reading about it, at least to cover the basics. Trying to learn by randomly discovering behaviors you do not understand and then asking about them on Stack Overflow is not a good approach. It will be difficult and will leave gaps in understanding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are evaluated via correct order of operations, and remember `false` evaluates to `0` and `true` to `1`

`!=` and `==` have equal precedence, evaluate left to right

`>` has greater precedence than `!=`, evaluate it first

```
//true
if(1 != 0 == 1)  => if ((1 != 0) == 1)  => if (1 == 1)  => true

//false
if(1 != 0 == 0)  => if ((1 != 0) == 0)  => if (1 == 0)  => false

//true
if(1 != 0 > 2)  => if (1 != (0 > 2))  => if (1 != 0)  =>  true
```

http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence